# date format in database of quiz module

Tags: 7

I make a quiz with quiz module and the start date is 1/8/2013 4:30 and the close time is 10/8/2013 4:30.
In the database it stored as this=>

```
1375315200(quiz open)
1376092800(quiz close)
```

which one is year, month and day?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function.

Example:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', 1299446702);
```

Check [Unix Timestamp Conversion Tools](http://www.epochconverter.com/) online

Comment: can you give me a code that convert this timestamps?

Comment: try `echo date('m/d/Y', "Your Timestamp");`

Comment: not working!and I want to convert unix timestamp to human time stamp like YYMMDD

Comment: It shows 01/01/1970

Comment: we can use this function

    function unix_timestamp_to_human ($timestamp = "", $format = 'Ymd- H:i:s')
    {
        if (empty($timestamp) || ! is_numeric($timestamp)) $timestamp = time();
        return ($timestamp) ? date($format, $timestamp) : date($format, $timestamp);
    }